Django StreamingHttpResponse streams locally but not in production
I am posting this question after a lot of research but didn't get any solution working for me. I don't know what am I doing wrong, as I am new to Django
Following is my code base for stream.py
import json
from django.http import StreamingHttpResponse
from decimal import Decimal

class DecimalEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
   
    def default(self, obj):        
        if isinstance(obj, Decimal):
            return str(obj)  # or float(obj)
        return super(DecimalEncoder, self).default(obj)

class StreamResponseMixin:   
    def stream_response(self, queryset, serializer_class, gen_message_func=None):
        
        def generate_stream():
            for item in queryset:
                serializer = serializer_class(item)
                yield self.gen_message(serializer.data, gen_message_func)

        response = StreamingHttpResponse(generate_stream(), content_type='text/event-stream')
        response['X-Accel-Buffering'] = 'no'  # Disable buffering in nginx
        response['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache'  # Ensure clients don't cache the data
        response['Transfer-Encoding'] = 'chunked'
        return response

    def gen_message(self, data, gen_message_func=None):
       
        if gen_message_func:
            return gen_message_func(data)
        return '{}\n'.format(json.dumps(data, cls=DecimalEncoder)) # Default behavior if no custom message generator is provided


Views.py
class PackageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet, StreamResponseMixin):
   
    queryset = Package.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action in ['list', 'modified']:
            return PackageListSerializer
        return PackageDetailSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        package_queryset = Package.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')

        package_queryset = package_queryset.select_related('customer', 'creator').prefetch_related(
            Prefetch('products', queryset=Product.objects.all()),
        )

        try:
            customer = Customer.objects.get(user=user)
            package_queryset = package_queryset.filter(customer=customer)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            pass

        return package_queryset

    @action(detail=False, methods=['GET'], url_path='stream-packages')
    def get_stream(self, *args, **kwargs):
        packages = self.get_queryset().iterator(chunk_size=50)
        return self.stream_response(queryset=packages, serializer_class=PackageListSerializer)

nginx.conf
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name abc.api.ai;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/abc.api.ai/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/abc.api.ai/privkey.pem;

        location / {
            if ($internal_ips = 0) {
                return 403;
            }
            proxy_pass http://abc-backend-staging:8000;
            include proxy.conf;
        }
        location /api/packages/stream-packages/ {
            proxy_pass http://abc-backend-staging:8000;
            include proxy.conf;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Connection "";
            chunked_transfer_encoding on;
            proxy_buffering off;
            proxy_request_buffering off;
        }
    }

proxy.conf which is inclueded in nginx.conf
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto "https";


entrypoint.sh as my application is being deployed via docker container
exec poetry run uvicorn myapplication.asgi:application --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000


I don't know what I am missing, though it is streaming on the localhost but not in production.
I have tried the various provided solutions regarding Nginx configuration posted over Github, StackOverflow, and Django official forum, but none of them work in my case. However, in most of the cases, setting "proxy_buffering off" was the solution but it didn't work in my case either.
I am facing the same problem as mentioned here but the provided solution doesn't work in my case
Additionally, for some API end-points, it rendered data after fetching all in a single go but for some, it even doesn't send data might that end-points contain bigger data as compared to others.
I am feeling down now after spending a couple of days solving this problem. Any kind of help will be much appreciated.
Thanks!

did you find a solution?

Unfortunately. No!

I found the solution to mine: setting nginx proxy_buffering to off. here: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_buffering
